# Retrieve OuterXML From XML Child Node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to retrieve the OuterXML for each speak tag.

For example, I need to retrieve this data for the first speak tag in test.ssml:

```
   <speak xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
      <voice name="en-US-GuyNeural">
         <prosody rate="0.00%">Test 1</prosody>
      </voice>
   </speak>
```

### index.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
require_once('src/Config.php');
$fileName = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.ssml';

$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
// $fileContent = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $fileContent );
$xml=simplexml_load_file($fileName);
$reader = new XMLReader();

foreach($xml->speak as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . " ::: " . htmlspecialchars( $reader->readOuterXml ( $child )  ). "<br>";
  }
```

### test.ssml

all tracks.mp3
        bookmarks.dat
     
     
        
           Test 1
        
     
     
        
           Test 2

### Current Output in Browser

[image: Current Output Image]

### Desired Output

[image: Desired Output Image]

Comment: Does `echo $child->asXML();` do any better (inside the loop).

Comment: @NigelRen After repeatedly refreshing my browser it finally displayed the correct output.  Pleas post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the XML directly using the SimpleXML function `asXML()` and don't need (as far as I can tell) the `XMLReader`...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($fileName);

foreach($xml->speak as $child)
{
    echo $child->asXML()."<br />";
}
```